# Computing the value of $\int^1_{-1}\:\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{e^x+x}}\:\mathrm{d}x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have encountered this integral and me and my colleagues cannot figure it out. I did prove that it is actually integrable (it is boundless for a certain $x_0$ as I will explain later), but I couldn't find a good way to solve it.

The integral is
$$
\int^1_{-1}\:\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{e^x+x}}\:\mathrm{d}x
$$

What I found already:

1. By Intermediate Zero Theorem on $(-1,0)$ there is a negative $x_0$ that nullifies the denominator. Thus, there the function is not defined and unbounded. We need to check that it is still integrable (improperly). Thus, we use Taylor Polynomial and we find that the denominator is asynptotic to $\sqrt[3]{(e^{x_0}+1)(x-x_0)}$. Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x-x_0}}$ is integrable for $x\to x_0$, we can proceed to finding the value.
2. Some euristic considerations on this part, which is the one I couldn't figure out. Those extrema bring to mind even/odd functions. This said, that, as well as substitution, seems complex since we cannot solve algebrically $e^x-x=t$. My hope was to divide the integral in "odd_function (morbid) + even_function (easy to integrate)" and nullify the odd one by using extrema.

Thank you.

Comment: 0.9153(appx) By Integral calculator.

Comment: Is there a reason you believe this has a closed form? Is it from some kind of competition?

Comment: We can try bounds rather that finding the actual one and try to minimize the error.

Comment: No closed form exist Using digamma,  gamma, etc

Comment: It was on a book. Unless its a mistake on the author side...

Comment: https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: Try this it might help you

Comment: Even it has no particular Antiderivative.

Comment: Using some other Techinques Like Converting integral to Sum there might be the solution but I couldn't want to approach that.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JeffreyHarkness: Wolfram Alpha calculates it as 0.915366 (which agrees with the value in the first comment).

Comment: @NickD, thanks for commenting.  I meant to say: by solving $e^x+x=0$ numerically, I find that the vertical asymptote occurs near $x=−0.56714$. Using numerical approximation in R, I find that the positive integral value from the asymptote to 1 is somewhere near 1.661607.

Comment: Can you tell us what book it came from?

Comment: Maybe we can use the Taylor series
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1/3}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n+1/3)}{\Gamma(1/3)}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: If you're willing to use Lambert-W functions (the inverse to the function $xe^x$), you can solve $e^x+x=u$ as $x=u-W(e^u)$. For instance, using this transforms the integral into $$\int_{1/e-1}^{e+1}\frac{u^{-1/3}}{1+W(e^u)}\text{ d}u$$

Comment: @PhoboHavuz. I am sorry ! I did not see your comment which is the last of a long list. I shall edit and give you the credit of this substitution. Cheers :-)

Comment: Yea unfortunately even mathematica fails to spit out a closed form and I cannot see any way to contour integrate or series bash this into something analytical so I think the best we can do is just an approximation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int^{+1}_{-1}\:\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{e^x+x}}$$

As @PhoboHavuz proposed in comments,
$$e^x+x=t \implies x=t-W\left(e^t\right) \implies dx=\frac{dt}{1+W\left(e^t\right)}$$
$$I=\int_{\frac{1-e}{e}}^{1+e} \frac{dt}{\sqrt[3]{t}
   \,\left(1+W\left(e^t\right)\right)}$$

Now, for *approximation*, we could replace $\frac{1}{1+W\left(e^t\right)}$ by its $[n,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ built around $t=0$.

The simplest is
$$P_1=\frac 1{(\Omega +1)}\,\frac {2 (\Omega +1)^2-t }{2 (\Omega +1)^2+ (2 \Omega -1)t}$$

To give an idea of their accuracy, the norms
$$\Phi_n=\int_{\frac{1-e}{e}}^{1+e}\left(\frac{1}{1+W\left(e^t\right)}-P_n  \right)^2\,dt$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \Phi_n \\
 1 & 1.164\times 10^{-2} \\
 2 & 7.318\times 10^{-5} \\
 3 & 8.019\times 10^{-7} \\
 4 & 9.955\times 10^{-9} \\
 5 & 1.284\times 10^{-10} \\
 6 & 1.638\times 10^{-12} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using these Padé approximants, after factorizations of numerator and denominator, the integrand write
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{t}}\,\frac {a_n \,\prod_{i=1}^n (t-r_i) } {b_n \,\prod_{i=1}^n (t-s_i) } $$ Using partial fractions, it becomes
$$ \frac{a_n}{b_n}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{t}}\,\Bigg[1+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A_i}{t-s_i}\Bigg]$$ which is more than simple to integrate, leading, as usual, to a sum of logarithms and a sum of arctangents.

As a function of $n$, some decimal representations of analytical results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result} \\
 1 & 0.808336 \\
 2 & 0.922701 \\
 3 & 0.914691 \\
 4 & 0.915434 \\
 5 & 0.915359 \\
 6 & 0.915367 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Building the Padé approximants is quite simple starting from the expansion around $t=0$
$$\frac{1}{1+W\left(e^t\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {P_n} {n!\,(\Omega+1)^{2n+1} }\,t^n$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & \Omega \\
 2 & -\Omega+2 \Omega^2 \\
 3 & \Omega-8 \Omega^2+6 \Omega^3 \\
 4 & -\Omega+22 \Omega^2-58 \Omega^3+24 \Omega^4 \\
 5 & \Omega-52 \Omega^2+328 \Omega^3-444 \Omega^4+120 \Omega^5 \\
 6 & -\Omega+114 \Omega^2-1452 \Omega^3+4400 \Omega^4-3708 \Omega^5+720
   \Omega^6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which show patterns which would be interesting to explore (the first one is trivial, the next are clearly related to Eulerian numbers).

Comment: That is way beyond my understanding, I fear. Nevertheless, thank you for the interesting answer.

Comment: @SimoneLicciardi. This is the same idea as Taylor series (which do not work in this case !).

Comment: Your $P_n$ is given by [OEIS A008517 "Second-order Eulerian triangle $T(n,k)$](https://oeis.org/A008517). Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. Thanks ! For the coeffcients, it is fine. But, what are the polynomials and how to generat them by reccurence if possible ? Cheers :-)

Comment: In fact you got (as you suggested) [Eulerian_numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Eulerian_numbers_of_the_second_order) (of the second order) and could use directly for $n>0$ :
$$P_n(\Omega)=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \ll n,k\gg (-\Omega)^{k+1}$$
the Eulerian numbers being obtained with the recurrence (except $k=0\to 1,k=n\to 0$) :
$$\left\langle\left\langle {n\atop k}\right\rangle\right\rangle=(k+1)\left\langle\left\langle {n-1\atop k}\right\rangle\right\rangle +(2n-k-1)\left\langle\left\langle {n-1\atop k-1}\right\rangle\right\rangle$$ (no polynomials found quickly). Cheers,

Comment: (well none except the Eulerian polynomial of second order from the link!)