# What could be these particular polynomials?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615889/computing-the-value-of-int1-1-frac1-sqrt3exx-mathrmdx), I found the following polynomials
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(x) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & x \\
 2 & 2 x^2-x \\
 3 & 6 x^3-8 x^2+x \\
 4 & 24 x^4-58 x^3+22 x^2-x \\
 5 & 120 x^5-444 x^4+328 x^3-52 x^2+x \\
 6 & 720 x^6-3708 x^5+4400 x^4-1452 x^3+114 x^2-x \\
 7 & 5040 x^7-33984 x^6+58140 x^5-32120 x^4+5610 x^3-240 x^2+x \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The first and last coefficients are obvious; the other ones seem to be Eulerian numbers of different kinds.

***What could they be ?***

**Edit**

After @MartinR's comment, defining
$$P_n(x)=(-1)^n\, Q_n(-x)$$ we face polynomials whose coefficients are  the second-order Eulerian numbers $E_2(n, k)$ with $E_2(0, k) = \delta_{0, k}$ as said in $OEIS$ (sequence $A340556$).

Starting from this, I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040942/second-order-eulerian-numbers-lamberts-w-function-and-schr%C3%B6ders-fourth-probl) relating the second-order EEulerian numbers and Lambert function (this is the origin of my problem). In his answer, @Marko Riedel proved that

$$\frac{1}{1+W(z)} = \sum_{m= 0}^\infty (-1)^m \,\frac{m^m}{m!}\,z^m$$

Comment: Apart from the signs, the coefficients apparently are https://oeis.org/A340556

Comment: @MartinR. Thanks for this. I found pieces of it and I suspected something close to Euler polynomials.

Comment: Partly with different order, I found in OEIS: A008517, A112007, A163936, A201637, A288874, A340556, A340556.

Comment: Direct triangle : [OEIS A112007](https://oeis.org/A112007)